# How drawtext on video using flutter ffmpeg 0.3.0

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

Hello I want to add text and image on video but my command not working with flutter ffmpeg 0.3.0

Here is my commands :

Working command code with only logo:

```
FlutterFFmpeg flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
flutterFFmpeg.execute('-i $video -i $logo -filter_complex "overlay=20:20" $output').then((rc) => 
print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
```

Not Working command code with logo and text:

```
FlutterFFmpeg flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
flutterFFmpeg.execute('-i $video -i $logo -filter_complex "overlay=20:20" drawtext=text=mytext $output').then((rc) => 
print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
```

**Please help me**

Comment: Can you elaborate "Not Working"? Do you have any errors? Is the problem with the flutter/dart end or with ffmpeg? Can you provide the log from ffmpeg?

Comment: Thanks for response i have solved it..

Comment: How did you solve it? Consider adding an answer to your question describing how you solved it. Then if someone else has the same question they will find your answer (imagine you finding this question and only finding *"i have solved it"* with no solution). Adding an answer can increase your reputation.

Comment: thanks for informed I have added the answer

Answer (score 3):

```
-i $video -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=5:2, drawtext=fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:fontfile=simple.ttf:text=hello" out.mp4
```

execute this command to add watermark with text in a flutter.

I was an error from fontfile don't forget to add fontfile correct path